# Delayed script loading by removing type attribute of `<script type="text/plain"... />` not working on firefox

Tags: javascript, html, dom, firefox, browser

I am currently working on custom cookie consent solution for NextJS which already seems to work pretty well with this approach:

All scripts in the head that should be loaded after consent is given are implemented like that:
`<script src="iSetSomeCookies.js" type="text/plain" data-cookieconsent />`
The `type="text/plain"` prevents the browser from loading and executing the script.
After the consent is given, I remove the `type` attribute, clone the node, delete the original `<script>` node and append it to the `<head>`. Otherwise the browser won't notice the change.

This approach works on Safari and Chrome but not on Firefox...
The code gets executed and also the `type` attribute gets removed and added as new script node. But in the network tab the script does not get loaded afterwards.

Is there a ways to get Firefox to reparse the DOM and load the script?

Here is the part of my script that gets executed after cookie consent is given:

```
const blockedScripts = document.querySelectorAll<HTMLScriptElement>(
  "script[data-cookieconsent]"
)
blockedScripts.forEach((script) => {
  script.removeAttribute("type")
  const copy = script.cloneNode()
  document.head.insertBefore(copy, script)
  script.remove()
})
```

I also tried to change the type to `text/javascript` and `application/javascript` but that's still the same behaviour and Firefox seems to ignore that change.

I have seen some solutions that work with `eval(this.innerHtml)` to get the script executed afterwards but I don't want to use `eval`.

Comment: *"The code gets executed and also the type attribute gets removed and added as new script node."* Before or after your code runs to update the nodes?

Comment: why not use link preload/prefetch then convert that to actual script tag, after the consent is fulfilled?

Comment: With _"The code..."_ I meant the forEach loop that iterates over the `<script>`-nodes and not the code from the script-node itself.
May be a bit confusing the way I described it.

Comment: @dwikristianto I'm not sure if that could solve my problem. The issue here is not that the mechanism is not modifying the script tag. The solution above is working on Safari and Chrome. It's just firefox that's not detecting the added/modified script tag in the head.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's interesting that Firefox won't run the code referenced by the cloned script (I can verify I saw that behavior with your original code). I think the simplest thing would be to just create new nodes, which seems to work:

```
const blockedScripts = document.querySelectorAll("script[data-cookieconsent]");
for (const blocked of blockedScripts) {
    const { parentElement, nextSibling } = blocked;
    blocked.remove();
    const script = document.createElement("script");
    for (const attr of blocked.attributes) {
        if (attr.name !== "type") {
            script.setAttributeNode(attr.cloneNode());
        }
    }
    parentElement.insertBefore(script, nextSibling);
}
```

That code also doesn't assume the `script` elements are in the `head` element; instead, it uses whatever parent element the original had.

Here it is in TypeScript (had to add `as Attr` after cloning the attribute since `cloneNode`'s return type is `Node`, and add an `if` to convince TypeScript that `parentElement` isn't `null`:

```typescript
const blockedScripts = document.querySelectorAll<HTMLScriptElement>("script[data-cookieconsent]");
for (const blocked of blockedScripts) {
    const { parentElement, nextSibling } = blocked;
    if (!parentElement) { // Will never be true
        throw new Error(`parentElement is null`);
    }
    blocked.remove();
    const script = document.createElement("script");
    for (const attr of blocked.attributes) {
        if (attr.name !== "type") {
            script.setAttributeNode(attr.cloneNode() as Attr);
        }
    }
    parentElement.insertBefore(script, nextSibling);
}
```

You might prefer the not-nullish assertion operator on `parentElement` instead; I *really* don't like using it, but there's a good argument for it here:

```typescript
const blockedScripts = document.querySelectorAll<HTMLScriptElement>("script[data-cookieconsent]");
for (const blocked of blockedScripts) {
    const { parentElement, nextSibling } = blocked;
    blocked.remove();
    const script = document.createElement("script");
    for (const attr of blocked.attributes) {
        if (attr.name !== "type") {
            script.setAttributeNode(attr.cloneNode() as Attr);
        }
    }
    parentElement!.insertBefore(script, nextSibling);
}
```

Comment: I modified your answer a bit but generally with this solution it works! I guess the `document.createElement("script")` instead of the `script.cloneNode()` does the trick.

Comment: Should this approach work for type="module" as well? for me the script files are downloaded but doesnt seem to be executed.