# Conditionally Enable Script Tag where type="module"

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to conditionally enable script tags in HTML using below code but it doesn't seem to work as expected.

```
function loadScript() {
  document.querySelectorAll('script[type="text/skip-hydration"]').forEach((script) => {
    script.setAttribute('type', 'module');
  });
}
```

The value of the type attribute is updated but the scripts are not loaded.

Below are the script tags in my page:

```
<script src="runtime.js" type="text/skip-hydration"></script>
<script src="polyfills.js" type="text/skip-hydration">
```

Can someone please guide what is the issue with above code?

**Update**
It seems that in order to execute these script we need to add it again to the dom.

```
  document.querySelectorAll('script[type="text/skip-hydration"]').forEach((script) => {
    script.setAttribute('type', 'module');
    document.body.appendChild(script);
  });
```

Please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Delayed script loading by removing type attribute of \`<script type="text/plain"... />\` not working on firefox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75832462/delayed-script-loading-by-removing-type-attribute-of-script-type-text-plain)

Comment: Thank you for your comment, I have already seen that but it doesnt seem to work with scripts where type ="module". I see the scripts downloaded in network tab, but not executed.

Answer (score 1):

You could replace each script element with a new one by [cloning it](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/cloneNode), changing the `type`, and using [`Element#replaceWith`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/replaceWith).

```js
document.querySelectorAll('script[type="text/skip-hydration"]').forEach(script => {
    const newScript = script.cloneNode();
    newScript.type = 'module';
    script.replaceWith(newScript);
});
```

Alternative shorter implementation:

```js
document.querySelectorAll('script[type="text/skip-hydration"]')
    .forEach(script => script.replaceWith(Object.assign(script.cloneNode(), 
       {type: 'module'})));
```

Comment: Thank you so much Unmitigated, with this code the script are shown as downloaded in the Network tab of dev tools, but it seems these scripts are not executed.

Comment: @NaveedAhmed Are you sure? I've tested it by adding `console.log('loaded')` at the top of each module and they are being loaded for me.

Comment: Yes I think so, please have a look at the home page https://www.mustakbil.com/

Comment: If the scripts are executed, the login button should display login dialog.

Comment: @NaveedAhmed Could you try adding a `console.log` at the top of each script to see if it gets called?

Comment: These are Angular generated bundles, let see see. One more thing these script are of type module, should it make any difference?

Comment: @NaveedAhmed Are you sure those scripts are meant to be loaded as modules? Have you tried using a regular script with `type="text/javascript"` (or just removing the type)?

Comment: Yes these are module and by default the markup Angular CLI generates has type set to module. I tried removing the type but it didnt work either.